# How to configure solr schema.xml

Tags: solr, solrj

I m a little downfallen by configuring the schema.xml for my wished searchresults.
Let me show u my use case:

Word in document: "ausschließlich" (without quotes)
Search string: "schließ" (without quotes)
so when I search for my searchstring, I want to find all the case, where "schließ" occours.
such as:
ausschließlich
schließend
schließen
...
but not
sch....
schl...
schli...
and so on..

this is my analyzer config:

```
<analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />  
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" />
</analyzer>
```

would you please help me to configure it?
thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about German processing in Solr [here](http://bit.ly/1fiQMnd) and [here](http://bit.ly/16Qk1ZA). The easiest way is to substitute `solr.NGramTokenizerFactory` with this code:

```
<filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="German"/>
```

Comment: that is the problem, it couldn't only be in german. it could also be in english, too.

Comment: You can make language-specific analysis: store different language data in different fields with different analysis. Read here: [http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageDetection](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageDetection)

Comment: ok, thanks... [this link](https://developer.s24.com/blog/08-13-2013/german_stemming_like_a_pro.html) looks very good, but where do i put the dic-files in solr?

Comment: the dictionaries are usually placed in the conf directory of your core